# Post-checkout + Docker in PhpStorm or localhost

Tags: php, git, docker, console, phpstorm

I need help with this problem, please. I have docker with (php_web, mysql) and every works fine. I want use Git in PhpStorm with (pre-commit, post-checkout, ...). But if checkout branches

```
git checkout #xyz
```

I get error

> "Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /project/libs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:103"

This problem is caused by calling the command on the local machine, not in the docker. But I don't know how edit my post-checkout.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker exec -i php_web /bin/sh
#ID
echo $$ #there is LocalMachines ID

echo -e "*********************************"
echo -e "*********GENERATE-PROXIES********"
echo -e "*********************************"


#regenerate proxies
#php bin/console orm:generate-proxies localhost:8100
php bin/console orm:generate-proxies
```

Answer (score 1):

You should, following the [`docker exec` man page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), try and execute directly the command you need:

```
docker exec -it php_web /bin/sh -c "php bin/console orm:generate-proxies"
```

At least, that would be executed in the context of the container, instead of the local machine.